# Can I use [[noreturn]] on non-void returning functions?

Tags: c++, c++11, return, undefined-behavior, noreturn

I've never seen [[[ noreturn ]]](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes) used on non-void returning functions before.

Is the following well defined?

```
[[ noreturn ]] int function();

int function(){
  while(true){/* impl */}
  return 0;
}
```

The reason the return type must be `int`, is because the function is passed to another function via a function pointer.

So assuming the caller looks something like this:

```
//call the non-returning function
int var = (*fptr)();

//use var some way (even though the function will never actually return)
std::cout << var;
```

will this exhibit any kind of undefined behavior?

Comment: You might run into pedantic trouble with the allowance of the implementation to assume that an infinite loop ends. ([link](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/161))

Comment: @chris I'm hoping to tag the return value with [[maybe_unused]] as well.

Comment: From the link you posted : *The behavior is undefined if the function with this attribute actually returns.*

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The standard specification on `[[noreturn]]` is in [dcl.attr.noreturn]. The entire normative texts reads:

> The *attribute-token* `noreturn` specifies that a function does not return. It shall appear at most once in
>   each *attribute-list* and no *attribute-argument-clause* shall be present. The attribute may be applied to
>   the *declarator-id* in a function declaration. The first declaration of a function shall specify the `noreturn`
>   attribute if any declaration of that function specifies the `noreturn` attribute. If a function is declared with
>   the `noreturn` attribute in one translation unit and the same function is declared without the `noreturn`
>   attribute in another translation unit, the program is ill-formed; no diagnostic required.
>
> If a function `f` is called where `f` was previously declared with the `noreturn` attribute and `f` eventually returns,
>   the behavior is undefined.

There is no mention of return *type*. The only thing that matters is that the function not return. If the function returns (whether `void` or `int` or `vector<vector<double>>`), then behavior is undefined. If the function doesn't return, the return type is immaterial.

Answer (score 10):

From the C++ standard *§7.6.8/p2 Noreturn attribute [dcl.attr.noreturn] (**Emphasis Mine**)*:

> **If a function f is called where f was previously declared with the
>   noreturn attribute and f eventually returns, the behavior is
>   undefined.** [ Note: The function may terminate by throwing an
>   exception. — end note ] [ Note: Implementations are encouraged to
>   issue a warning if a function marked [[noreturn]] might return. — end
>   note ]

Since your function will never reach the `return 0;` there's no UB.

Comment: How does this answer the question? OP knows it shouldn't return, he's asking about its type.

Comment: How does the standard quote clarify that it *is* ub? OP's function doesn't eventually return.

Comment: @Barry doesn't it return `0`?

Comment: @101010 It'll never get to that line.

Answer (score 1):

I have found one practical example of a non-void `[[noreturn]]` function. It is in a case, when used in `?:` operator to provide a correct result type of `?:` operator:

```
template <class T> [[noreturn]] T fail(char const *s) noexcept { puts(s); exit(1); }
enum E { V1, V2 };
int f(E e) {
  return (e == V1) ? 1 : (e == V2) ? 2 : fail<E>("bad e");
}
```

Note: One could have a feeling that `[[noreturn]]` functions in `?:` operator could be ignored for calculation of `?:` result type. But it is not possible because `[[noreturn]]` is not a part of result type of an expression (`fail<T>("")` has result type `T` and not `[[noreturn]] T`).

Comment: Also useful for a callback function, when the return type is pre-determined.